# Linq to Sql - Query list of distinct items with multiple joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

I'm trying to achieve a Linq query that is a little bit tricky.

### DB structure :

- Table A : idA, nameA
- Table B : idB, idA, nameB
- Table C : idC, idA, nameC
- Table D : idD, idB, idC, nameD

  - *(idB and idC are both nullable)*

All fields are mandatory.

[Structure Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeEmz.png)

### Expected :

I'd like to retrieve :

- a list of A items (distinct)

  - with the 10 first D items (from B OR C)

    - with a predicate applied on found D items

Comment: What data structure do you want in the output? Flat? or nested?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan I'd like to get the D items nested into each A Item !

Comment: Is `idB` and `idC` both must not null? or must not null only one of them?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan idB and idC are both nullable. In fact, as you guessed, there is always one of them with a value assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to `LEFT JOIN` `tableD` with `tableB` and `tableC`.

```
var augmentedD =
    from d in tableD
    join b in tableB on d.IdB equals b.IdB into bs
    join c in tableC on d.IdC equals c.IdC into cs
    from b in bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    let idAA = b != null ? b.IdA : c != null ? c.IdA : (int?) null
    where idAA != null
    let idA = idAA.Value
    select new
    {
        idA,
        d
    };
```

Then, `GroupJoin` `tableA` to that result.

```
var nestedA = from a in tableA
    join d in augmentedD on a.IdA equals d.idA into g
    select
    new
    {
        A = a,
        D = g.OrderBy(x => x.d.NameD)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(x => x.d)
            .ToList()
    };
```

---

### Edit

If you want to put additional predicate, then put `Where` statement after `tableD`

```
var augmentedD =
    from d in tableD.Where(predicate)
    join b in tableB on d.IdB equals b.IdB into bs
    join c in tableC on d.IdC equals c.IdC into cs
    from b in bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    let idAA = b != null ? b.IdA : c != null ? c.IdA : (int?) null
    where idAA != null
    let idA = idAA.Value
    select new
    {
        idA,
        d
    };
```